# No able to create Device object for SyncResponse Payload

Tags: java, actions-on-google

As I understood, the Payload for SyncResponse was an array of type Device.

My problem is that I am not able to create an instance (don't have access) of type Device defined inside of SyncResponse  - Payload - Device.

When I `import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload.Device;` I receive an error that "cannot be resolved" and as result, the Device references has "Device cannot be resolved to a type" error.

If I use `com.google.api.services.actions_fulfillment.v2.model.Device`, following that SyncResponse.Payload.Device is not visible as shown on the left side of the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT3po.png) (I can't upload pictures), I can't cast.

As I missed the add code before, let's use from OnOff reference page, where the errors are possible to replicate.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.DisconnectRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.ExecuteRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.ExecuteResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.QueryRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.QueryResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SmartHomeApp;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload.Device;

public class MyActionsApp extends SmartHomeApp {

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public SyncResponse onSync(@NotNull SyncRequest syncRequest, @Nullable Map<?, ?> headers) {
        Payload payload = new Payload();
        payload.setAgentUserId("1836.15267389");
        payload.setDevices(new Device[] {
            new Device.Builder().setId("123")
                  .setType("action.devices.types.LIGHT")
                  .addTrait("action.devices.traits.OnOff")
                  .setName(
                      Collections.singletonList("AAA bulb A19 color hyperglow"),
                      "lamp1",
                      Collections.singletonList("reading lamp")
                  )
                  .setWillReportState(true)
                  .setAttributes(new JSONObject()
                      .put("commandOnlyOnOff", false)
                  )
                  .setDeviceInfo("BrandX", "hg11", "1.2", "5.4")
                  .setCustomData(new JSONObject()
                      .put("fooValue", 12)
                      .put("barValue", false)
                      .put("bazValue", "dancing alpaca")
                      .toString()
                  )
                  .build() });
        return new SyncResponse(syncRequest.getRequestId(), payload);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(DisconnectRequest request, Map<?, ?> headers) {        
    }

    @Override
    public ExecuteResponse onExecute(ExecuteRequest request, Map<?, ?> headers) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public QueryResponse onQuery(QueryRequest request, Map<?, ?> headers) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How should I create a Device object, or cast it?

P.S.: Sorry for not be clear before.

Comment: Please give a little more details and background  on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just added more details.

Comment: Can you verify that it is picking the right `Device` object by explicitly using the type `SyncResponse.Payload.Device`?

Comment: I believe so. Is the import statement is importing the wrong one? By the way, the one that I starter was the [Thermostat](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/thermostat), and even tried to explicit use ```com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload.Device``` with the same "cannot be resolved to a type" error.

Comment: @NickFelker I did some additional tests and if I convert MyActionsApp to Kotlin, the application is able to see the Device subclass. Also if I change SyncResponse, moving Device one level down, that becomes visible to Java, but not the subclass Builder. So far for this case, I could check that classes 2 levels down are not visible to Java code, but are visible to Kotlin.
I tested with Java 8 (AdoptOpenJDK) and 11 (Oracle) on MacOS. I don't have knowledge Kotlin visibility, but can you give more details about your environment where the Java application worked out of the box using subclasses?

Comment: I don't know that there's anything unique about my setup. It's a fairly standard IntelliJ project with the library as a dependency.

Comment: I just build the project using Gradle, completely out of the IDE and was able to compile and run the tests. Seems that is something with the Eclipse compiler. I even tried to install the Kotlin plugin and add the kotlin-reflect and kotlin-stdlib as compile dependencies, but without success (that dependencies are not necessary if I use Gradle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a JDT Core [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548596) and is fixed on the Eclipse version 2019-09.

Answer (score 0):

It's not readily clear what your issue is in particular. The documentation contains a lot of examples on how to create a proper `SyncResponse` with an array of `Device` objects.

From [OnOff reference page](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/onoff):

```
@NotNull
@Override
public SyncResponse onSync(@NotNull SyncRequest syncRequest, @Nullable Map<?, ?> headers) {
  Payload payload = new Payload();
  payload.setAgentUserId("1836.15267389");
  payload.setDevices(new Device[] {
      new Device.Builder()
          .setId("123")
          .setType("action.devices.types.LIGHT")
          .addTrait("action.devices.traits.OnOff")
          .setName(
              Collections.singletonList("AAA bulb A19 color hyperglow"),
              "lamp1",
              Collections.singletonList("reading lamp")
          )
          .setWillReportState(true)
          .setAttributes(new JSONObject()
              .put("commandOnlyOnOff", false)
          )
          .setDeviceInfo("BrandX", "hg11", "1.2", "5.4")
          .setCustomData(new JSONObject()
              .put("fooValue", 12)
              .put("barValue", false)
              .put("bazValue", "dancing alpaca")
              .toString()
          )
          .build()
  });
  return new SyncResponse(syncRequest.getRequestId(), payload);
}
```